# Convert ByteArray with negative values into String

Tags: java, arrays, string, encoding

I read a byte array from a file and I get negative values. The file is formatted like this:

```
{Ü¸¨~»I“•›"Ïï5≥¸ÁqŸJ(#R8é!ÈéÎ∏ù;”ˆå"gçø è˝:kfŸåÿ|=–x≤‚˛åë2Õqπ˜À\2€”| . 
¡∂"t4ïÊ'‹ö‰ÃÊÒ-˛™f⁄N‰;dçbÇ™u∞∫ß¥æ´®u(o•ˆ>≥+     ‰Û7aÄx”ßπﬁ  R∂éI˝"Œ
áä √ép´m™ù”[—w&∫&YNÂ¸∑,˚ä?ØçâjSı¢◊·T~7Œá«ôn–È^ˆ∆ú^   
„nôãwuﬂbŒHv≈œJ®(ﬂaNÚ?™º°3Å&mz†ﬁÛ∞Ï|òÅ÷ÚÔJX‘`oü0ÒYòg~¡}àî!MI
UF‹—*KM$Õˇ_¡’î¡7Œ…l„C†…Z∂AŒ!0ï≠g'ÿú[¸$Û~hìÎ*¥◊i àÒ˜¸nq#∞oã¢«K ÛëÓ^:y    
Âœ9Üå¬ÁH√ªm˛MOo/[TﬂÜ˙<¿¿óÇµ~|∂⁄ôúRñd1˜RÚTπ<Mâ,ùR-ÙZï˘*ØjR9‚˚Úè@ƒDd˜
ÂëH∫n”®*úGdÄí§]Ò:¿F∫∆d3ı÷ }äÇﬂN•ºÜÔHODÊÔÛ'ãH´É¬»Ñc1•}w+dv0´¸ñgŸkæ-Ídp– 
A/5˜ƒÅ©8»GWJ≠Qé
```

I read the byte array with this code:

```
byte[] bytesArray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);                                                        
fis.read(bytesArray); //read file into bytes[]
```

When i try to convert this to string by using:

```
ret = new String(bytesArray, "UTF-8");
```

I get a string with strange symbols (�) where there are negative bytes in the array. How could I solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Most likely your file is not a text file encoded in UTF-8. You need to know what you are reading to get it right.

Comment: I suggest that you use the Linux `file` command ( `man 1 file` ) to try to figure out what kind of file you are dealing with.   This doesn't look like UTF-8 encoded text to me.

Comment: Why? String is not a container for binary data.